# python for loop using index to create values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a very simple for loop problem and I haven't found a solution in any of the similar questions on Stack. I want to use a for loop to create values in a pandas dataframe. I want the values to be strings that contain a numerical index. I can make the correct value print, but I can't make this value get saved in the dataframe. I'm new to python.

```
# reproducible example
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(5)})
# for loop to add a row with an index
for i in range(5):
    print("data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)) # this prints the value that I want
    df1['file'] = "data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)
```

This loop prints the exact value that I want to put into the 'file' column of `df1`, but when I look at df1, it only uses the last value for the index.

```
   x        file
0  0  data_4.txt
1  1  data_4.txt
2  2  data_4.txt
3  3  data_4.txt
4  4  data_4.txt
```

I have tried using `enumerate`, but can't find a solution with this. I assume everyone will yell at me for posting a duplicate question, but I have not found anything that works and if someone points me to a solution that solves this problem, I'll happily remove this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better ways to create a DataFrame, but to answer your question:

Replace the last line in your code:

```
df1['file'] = "data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)
```

with:

```
df1.loc[i, 'file'] = "data_{0}.txt".format(i)
```

For more information, read about the `.loc` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

On the same page, you can read about accessors like `.at` and `.iloc` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do list-comprehension:

```
df1['file'] = ["data_{i}.txt".format(i=i) for i in range(5)]
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   x        file
0  0  data_0.txt
1  1  data_1.txt
2  2  data_2.txt
3  3  data_3.txt
4  4  data_4.txt
```

OR at the creating of DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(5), 'file': ["data_{i}.txt".format(i=i) for i in range(5)]})
print(df1)
```

OR:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'x':i, 'file': "data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)} for i in range(5)])
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found success with the .at method

```
for i in range(5):
    print("data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)) # this prints the value that I want
    df1.at[i, 'file'] = "data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)
```

Returns:

```
   x        file
0  0  data_0.txt
1  1  data_1.txt
2  2  data_2.txt
3  3  data_3.txt
4  4  data_4.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

when you assign a variable to a dataframe column the way you do -
using the df['colname'] = 'val', it assigns the val across all rows.
That is why you are seeing only the last value.

Change your code to:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(5)})
# for loop to add a row with an index
to_assign = []
for i in range(5):
    print("data_{i}.txt".format(i=i)) # this prints the value that I want
    to_assign.append(data_{i}.txt".format(i=i))
##outside of the loop - only once - to all dataframe rows
df1['file'] = to_assign.
```

As a thought, pandas has a great API for performing these type of actions without for loops.
You should start practicing those.